# message_set of Django model

Tags: python, django, model

i'm new with Django and as I read the code, I don't understand the message_set attribute of Django model(called Room):

```
def room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    **room_messages = room.message_set.all()**
    participants = room.participants.all()
```

portion of Models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
participants = models.ManyToManyField(
    User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: where message_set came from? and what does it do? can anyone help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a `ForeignKey` from `Message` to `Room`, Django will add a relation in reverse to the from the `Room` model to its related `Message`s. By default this relation is named `modelname_set` with *`modelname`* the name of the origin of the model. You can specify another name by overriding the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

If you thus access the relation in reverse, you get all `Message` objects with `room` as there room, an equivalent query to `room.message_set.all()` is thus `Message.objects.filter(room=room)`.